# DOMSubtreeModified Event (and/or replacement) on solely <a> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I've noticied the DOMSubtreeModified event is being deprecated (which is sad news), but I was wondering if there's a way to detect a change in every single  tag on a page (I know - this can be really costly, but it has its purpose).

Basically, I want to know whenever an `<a>` tag (node) is created/modified so I can quickly scan its .href and see if it matches a pattern I'm looking for (if it is, I want to redirect it to run my JS (irrelevant to this) instead of navigating to said link). I need this to be generic (I don't know IDs/divs/anything except that they're `<a href>`s, and they have a specific URL pattern I'm looking for.

I know the support for this even is patchy but right now it'd only be used as a Chrome extension (Firefox to come soon after, so I'd have to tinker with it), so it should be okay for now.

Let me know if there are extra questions. Thanks!

Comment: why would you listen for the modify when you could just catch the click later? If it's the behaviour you're interested in, then alter the behaviour instead of hunting around and doing work for nothing.

Comment: I'm kind of a jQuery noob (haven't played with it in years)...is there a way to catch a click on a specific tag before it navigates? Is there a way to do that only to those that match the pattern I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the link action when it happens instead. What is the pattern you are looking for? It's just a matter of "selecting" the right `<a>`s. jQuery has attribute [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for just about any occasion, "starts with", "ends with", "contains", "equals", etc...

```
$('a[href="http://notHere.com"]').on('click',function(event){
    alert("omg don't go there!");
    //window.location="http://www.goHere.com";
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smNNW/6/)

**As per comment:**

If your page will be changed dynamically you will need to delegate the event binding to something which will definitely always exist, and contain you target.

```
$('body').on('click','a[href="http://notHere.com"]',function(event){
    alert("omg don't go there!");
    //window.location="http://www.goHere.com";
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This puts the click handler on the `<body>` and from there it watches for clicks on the appropriate anchors. If you can get closer, go for it, eg: `$('#mainContent')`

Comment: All gCal invite links begin with something like `http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE` followed by a delimited list of attributes which describe the event.

I wrote a little JS script to log into your gCal and check if you're available for that time/offer to add it to your calendar for you so you don't have to go looking at that timeslot on your calendar. It was for a class project, and was hosted on a specific website, but I want to make it a Chrome extension so it'll work on any page you navigate to :D

Comment: I also had plans to build on it with things like priority list for your different calendar, so if you had one event on your "Free Time" calendar and the new event was on your "Work Obligations" calendar, you could configure it to automagically delete the old event and add the new event. Stuff like that. It's pretty nifty standalone, but I've been trying to get it to work as an extension for awhile, and part of that is being able to sniff for any appropriate links

Comment: I've discovered one problem here: What's possible is that if the DOM changes (i.e. the link is generated) after my script loads, this isn't catching the click (see:[link](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html#toc-individual))). If you go through and generate the HTML using that form, my JS (which was injected when the page/tab loaded) doesn't catch the event. If you change tabs and come back, it works as expected.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I have it working now for the most part, although it isn't quite working on things like Facebook or gMail, not sure why though. The extension loads/runs (I can get `alert`s to show up), but the listener isn't catching the link click in those cases. Possibly due the intense amount of `div`s it's nested under?

Comment: The link(s) I'm talking about are the ones generated by Google Calendar (e.g. [from this page](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html#toc-individual)) and in terms of code, it's what we've been discussing...`$('body').on("click",'a[href^="https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE"]', function(event) {alert('This will not fire');});` whereas if I put the `alert` just within `main.js`, it fires. It works on most pages, but it isn't catching if you were to take the link, paste it into gMail(or Facebook), send it to yourself, and then click on it :/

Comment: Not all links are as they appear. The key is to inspect the DOM, target appropriately, and be mindful of other javascript which may be in effect. The reason I asked for code (or better yet a live link or jsFiddle) was to see what the living "links" are, and why they might now be behaving as you'd like.

Comment: Indeed - I discovered that FB was wrapping their links, so I changed my pattern to contain the URL I'm looking for. Also, it seems like gMail isn't working because the DOM objects I'm looking for are in an `iframe`. I'm assuming I'll be able to put a clause in for gMail specifically, but I'm worried about making this generalizable...an arbitrary page could have the link in an arbitrary `iframe`...